# Does Salesforce Marketing Cloud support Android App Links

Tags: android, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud, android-deep-link, android-app-links

I know Deep linking with iOS application is supported by SFMC and I found documentation at [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_implement_ios_universal_link.htm&type=5)

But I am unable to find any documentation which provides details on supporting deeplining for Android application. Does marketing cloud supports android app links at all? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it still don't, but you might want to check with support once.  See if you could use some work around' like https://app.urlgeni.us/

Answer (score 0):

I would say is partially supported as depends on the platform, not really on the email coded as is exemplified [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links#app-links-vs-deep-links):

> However, if other apps installed on a user's device can handle the same intent, users might not go directly to your app. For example, clicking a URL in an email from a bank might lead to a dialog asking the user whether to use the browser or the bank's own app to open the link.

So that depends on the configuration of the itents of the app to catch that request and how the user has configured the default handler on the device's system settings.